# Error on my ASP.Net Web Application on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

My application on `web server` was working fine. Due to some (maybe) windows update on server, I am receiving error on my application as follows.

I tried re-build and re-deploying my application but no luck.

**ERROR*****

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
> compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
> review the following specific error details and modify your source
> code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'ASP.mnusidebarctrl_ascx'
> exists in both
> 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
> Files\root\2d2d9ef8\7f05df3f\App_Web_zrkdma3q.dll' and
> 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
> Files\root\2d2d9ef8\7f05df3f\App_Web_rxbq2o50.dll'

Source Error:

> Line 1072:         Line 1073:
> [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()] Line 1074:
> private global::ASP.mnusidebarctrl_ascx
> @__BuildControlmnuSidebarCtrl() { Line 1075:
> global::ASP.mnusidebarctrl_ascx @__ctrl; Line 1076:

What is the cause?

Please help, thanks

Comment: Hum, that's quite rare for the production server. Is that server funning full edition of IIS? I would stop the server, and then delete the contents of the Temporary asp.net files folder. Then re-start the web server.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal thats what I told to hosting provider to delete temp files. They said we cannot restart as our other clients are using the services. :(